# waterproofing back room of Garage

Tags: water, garage, waterproofing, sealer

On back of garage built a tool room.Water comes in tool room due to small hill I tried to dig 3 ft around back and side water still comes in.Is there a solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is it you tried to dig? Did you actually dig something or just try to dig something?

Comment: VTC - Step back and look at what you wrote. How can it begin to provide the detail needed to begin to evaluate then yet provide any sort of answer. If you can add more information such as pictures, floor and foundation type, how the addition was merged with garage siding and roof and what the grade of the back side area looks like then maybe the close vote can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "trying" (whatever that means) to dig 3 feet, "do" dig, rake, and generally fix the slope of the ground for 8-12 feet (3-4 meters) adjacent to your building so that it slopes away from the building by at least 1/8" per foot, or 1 cm per meter (whichever you are more comfortable measuring, per local standards.) 3 feet or 1 meter is not nearly far enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that the small hill is putting the water into the room, then a French drain is the right solution. However, sometimes the source of water is a poorly positioned downspout that needs an extension, a leak in a ceiling, or a dozen other problems. Don't forget to check if water is coming in under a door. You can look up the proper procedure for a French drain on the internet. Whatever you do, if you are digging a drain, the drain has to be deeper than the floor you are trying to protect or it will simply gather water and make the problem worse.